Reduce relational expression in SymPy
I'm using Sympy module to work with inequalities. An example of expression would be:
expression = (x > 852 | y <= 7) & (x > 704 | y >= 6)
Then I want to apply a constraint:
constraint = x <= 759 (known to be true)
Then the term (x > 852) is False
The expected expression should be simplified to:
(y <= 7) & (x > 704 | y >= 6)
Is this possible with Sympy?
An example for the code would be:
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')

# (x > 852 | y <= 7) & (x > 704 | y >= 6)
expression = (sympy.Gt(x, 852) | sympy.Le(y, 7)) & (sympy.Gt(x, 704) | sympy.Ge(y, 6))

# x <= 759
condition = sympy.Le(x, 759)

# This will only do direct substitution of the condition
expression = expression.subs(condition, True)


There is probably a better way of doing this but at least this gives the expected output:
In [10]: to_dnf(expression & condition).simplify().subs(condition, True)
Out[10]: y ≤ 7 ∧ (y ≥ 6 ∨ x > 704)

I would not expect that to scale up very well to larger systems of inequalities though.

The issue is within the logic of your code. In your code you're substituting the condition x<=759 and by doing so you are simply performing a singular replacement instead of evaluating the expression as a whole. To fix this, you should use either simplify or satisfiable which take conditions when simplifying expressions. You could possibly use sympy.simplify and simple logical conditions to properly simplify the expression to your needs.

Go ahead and substitute in a value for x with the condition you know to be true, let it simplify, and then remove the temporary variable (p):
from sympy import var
from sympy.abc import x, y
p=var('p',positive=True)
eq = ((x > 852) | (y <= 7)) & ((x > 704) |( y >= 6))
>>> eq.subs(x,759-p).subs(p,-x+759)
(y <= 7) & ((y >= 6) | (x > 704))

You should probably add the known relationship, too:
>>> _ & (x<=759)
(x <= 759) & (y <= 7) & ((y >= 6) | (x > 704))

